# Write result into csv file in nodeJS

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, loops, csv

I'm trying to loop through a string of url images then grab the 3 rgb value colors which splashy.js does, then using csv-writer to display the data in csv file, but unfortunately instead of adding to the file csv-writer keeps rewriting the file rather then adding to the file. How to fix this?

[image]

Comment: Please post your code, not an image of your code

Comment: Just updated the post sorry for that

Comment: You should post the code without your fixes ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just add `append: true` to your `createCsvWriter` call argument, it would somewhat work, though the order of CSV records depends on the order `splashy.fromUrl` finishes its work. Also, because you use `append` mode, you won't get the header record in the output CSV.

Instead, you can define `csvWriter` outside of your `imgs` loop.

```js
const csvWriter = createCsvWriter({
  path: "./data/output.csv",
  header: [
    { id: "url", title: "URl" },
    { id: "color1", title: "Color" },
    { id: "color2", title: "Color" },
    { id: "color3", title: "Color" }
  ]
});

const promiseForRecords = imgs.map(async img => {
  const colors = await splashy.fromUrl(img.toString());
  return {
    url: img,
    color1: colors[0],
    color2: colors[1],
    color3: colors[2]
  };
});

Promise.all(promiseForRecords)
  .then(records => csvWriter.writeRecords(records))
```

This way, the record order is guaranteed and you'll get the header record in the first line.

The advantage of using `csv-writer` library here is that you don't need to worry whether any image URLs contain comma `,` or double-quotes `"` which need to be escaped in CSV.

If you do want to write CSV line-by-line, you can use `.reduce` instead of `.map` like this:

```js
imgs.reduce(async (promise, img) => {
  await promise;

  const colors = await splashy.fromUrl(img.toString());
  const records = [
    {
      url: img,
      color1: colors[0],
      color2: colors[1],
      color3: colors[2]
    }
  ];
  return csvWriter.writeRecords(records);
}, Promise.resolve());
```

Answer (score 3):

This can also be achieved without depending on any 3rd party npm module .
We can generate csv files by use core node.js functionalities.

For that case I need to understand in what format you are looking for the csv file.

A basic csv file can be generated as :

```
let headers = ["h1","h2","h3","h4"].join("\t");
let row1    = ["r1","r2","r3","r4"].join("\t");
let row2    = ["t1","t2","t3","t4"].join("\t");

let writeStream = headers+"\n"+row1+"\n"+row2+"\n";

let fs = require("fs");

fs.writeFile("file.csv", writeStream)
.then(file => {{file details}})
.catch(err => err)
```

Answer (score 2):

On the first line,  `csv-writer#createobjectcsvwriter` accepts an optional parameter to specify that you want to append to the file instead of overwriting it. You can find the details on the [npm package description](https://www.npmjs.com/package/csv-writer#createobjectcsvwriterparams)

> createObjectCsvWriter(params) Parameters:
>
> ```
> params <Object>
>    - append <boolean> (optional)
>      Default: false. When true, it will append CSV records to the specified file. If the file doesn't exist, it will create one.
> ```

Your line should read something like:

```
const createCsvWriter = require("csvwriter").createObjectCsvWriter({ append: true })
```

Comment: It's an option to the `createObjectCsvWriter` function, you should use something like `const createCsvWriter = require("csvwriter").createObjectCsvWriter({ append: true }) `. I have upated my answer.

Comment: Yes thank you that fixed that , but know im getting .    UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch()

Comment: Glad it worked. I would suggest that you accept the answer, and recreate a new question, as it's unrelated, and it won't be manageable in the comments. Thx.

Comment: Ah, im sorry about that its my only my second time using this  did know about the 90 minute wait just so tired working on this but ill go ahead an revert it back and create a new post when the timer done is up appericate your time did mean to come off rude.